# CrawlSpider fetches only a subset of the matched links in the first page, then moves to scrape links in second page

Tags: python, scrapy

Crawlspider fetches only a subset of the matched links on the first page of the listings. Soon after, it moves to the second page where it successfully follows all matched links, exactly as intended. How to make Crawlspider follow all matched links before proceding in the second page?

I have added the "process_links='link_filter''" argument in the second Rule and verified it matched all links as intended, but it follows a seemingly semi-random subset of them.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import re

class ClassfiedsSpider(CrawlSpider):        
    name = "classfieds_tests"
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/classifieds/category/laptops/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=("ul[class=ipsPagination] > li[class=ipsPagination_next] > a")), process_links='pl_tmp'),# callback='parse_start_url'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=("h4 > div > a")), process_links='link_filter', callback='parse_classfied', follow=False),
    )
    def pl_tmp(self, links):
        print([link.url for link in links])
        return links

    def link_filter(self, links):
        print("links: ", [re.search("(item/)(.*?)(-)", link.url).group(2) for link in links])
        #print("links: ", [link.url for link in links])
        return links
```

I expected that Crawlspider would move to the second page only after it finishes following the links in the first.

Comment: See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order

Answer (score 0):

After ~10 hours of digging through the source code, I was able to spot the problem in the way the scheduler stores requests in memory. The solution was to change it to a queue(FIFO) so that the older requests get fetched first. It can easily be changed by setting in settings.py:

```
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```